# Reshaping multiple variables in wide format to nodes and edges for network analysis

Tags: r, network-analysis, data-management

I am having trouble preparing a dataset in R for network analysis. I have a set of ten non-mutually exclusive race/ethnicity dummy variables from survey data in a wide format of just over 150K responses (see R code below for sample data)

```
resp <- 150000
race_01 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_02 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_03 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_04 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_05 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_06 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_07 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_08 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_09 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
race_10 <- rbinom(n=resp, size=1, prob = runif(1,min = 0, max = 1))
dat <- cbind(race_01, race_02, race_03, race_04, race_05, race_06, race_07, race_08, race_09, race_10)
dat
```

Googling around, I haven't been able to find a method to transition this dataset to one of nodes and edges for network analyses. Any assistance or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are we to assume that rows are nodes in this network?  I'm not sure we have enough data to define relationships with the data you provided.

Comment: In this case, each category of race is a node. I envision making a network graph showing the relationship of races commonly chosen together.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)
g<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(dat)
plot(g, edge.arrow.size=.6)
```

Comment: When I ran the first line after the library call, I got the following error message: Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  : 
  At structure_generators.c:274 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix